# lettuce: run code before scenario outline

Tags: python, testing, scenarios, lettuce

I am using lettuce 0.1.35 with Python 2.6 and I noticed that when I define a scenario outline, the code defined with an `@lettuce.before.each_scenario` decorator is not run before each instance of the scenario outline - when I repeat each scenario definition as a distinct scenario, this code is run.

How to have some code run between each scenario defined by the same scenario outline ?

Comment: You mean that it isn't being run before each example of the scenario outline? If that's the case, it's a bug.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Then you should report it as a bug.

Comment: I noticed the same thing. Is this fixed?